Unable to edit Azure PostgreSQL database created with Bicep
I have an Azure PostgreSQL Flexible Server and a database 'mydb' created with Bicep and Github Actions. When creating a database with Bicep, the database owner is set to the 'azuresu' role which is entirely managed by the Azure platform. I have set the server admin by Entra ID authentication using the service principal account which is running the deployment actions.
How can I create new schemas and tables in the database 'mydb'? For example, if I try to use the Entra ID administrator account to grant privileges to itself on database 'mydb' in Github Actions:
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydb TO "GitHub Actions Deployment Account";

results in warning/error:

WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "mydb"

Is there any workaround to use any other database that the default 'postgres' database in Azure PostgreSQL Flexible Server? It seems that the server administrator has absolutely no privileges to edit any other database than 'postgres' or the system databases, and the 'azuresu' account is not usable by end users.
EDIT: I'm able to create a new database with SQL so that the account used in the creation gets admin permissions to the database. But if the database is created with Bicep, the deployment service account does not get admin rights. So the workaround is to use SQL but it seems that databases created with Bicep are unusable. This is probably a bug in Bicep?

Are you able to open the database in azure portal?

@Bhavani yes and I am able to connect to it from Azure Data Studio and run queries on public schemas like: SELECT * from information_schema.tables; But for example, the CREATE SCHEMA operation fails.

Have you tried any bicep script so far! @Lazer

@Jahnavi it seems that there is no way to control who is assigned as the database owner in Bicep. We have decided to use Bicep for server deployment only, while the database is created with SQL in the deployment pipeline. I am curious to know if you have found any Bicep workarounds for this, however!

I could see it is a limitation in bicep and is it possible to change the owner in your environment! @Lazer
